# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push') at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:15:23)

Tags: javascript

```
add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Updating List......")
    tit = document.getElementById("title").value;
    desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
    if (localStorage.getItem('itemsJson') == null){
        itemJsonArray = [];
        itemJsonArray.push([tit, desc]);
        localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
    }
    else{
        itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('itemJson')
        itemJsonArray = JSON.parse(itemJsonArrayStr);
        itemJsonArray.push([tit, desc]);
        localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArrayStr))
    }
})
```

main.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
at HTMLButtonElement. (main.js:14:23)

Comment: itemJsonArray.push([tit, desc]); this method is execute in if block but not executing in else block.

Comment: You're saving to `itemsJson` and reading from `itemJson`.

Answer (score 1):

In the else block, you have a typo "itemJson". It should be **itemsJson**

```
itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('itemsJson')
```